# Heap corruption when quit displaying image OpenCV

Tags: debugging, opencv

I'm doing some iamge mathching based on this tutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

It works well alone, but when I put it into a function and call it from main function, there are heap corruption. The program shows the image, then when I press space to close the program, it breaks.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    // Part 2 panorama
    Mat im1=imread("panorama_image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat im2=imread("panorama_image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    immosaic(im1,im2);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the mosaic function, copied from the tutorial

```
void immosaic(Mat im_object, Mat im_scene)
{
    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 400;
    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

    detector.detect( im_object, keypoints_object );
    detector.detect( im_scene, keypoints_scene );

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
    extractor.compute( im_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
    extractor.compute( im_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
        if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
    }

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
    {
        if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
            good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
    }

    Mat img_matches;
  drawMatches( im_object, keypoints_object, im_scene, keypoints_scene,
               good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

  //-- Localize the object
  std::vector<Point2f> obj;
  std::vector<Point2f> scene;

  for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  }

  Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

  //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
  std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
  obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( im_object.cols, 0 );
  obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( im_object.cols, im_object.rows ); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, im_object.rows );
  std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

  perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

  //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( im_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );

  //-- Show detected matches
  namedWindow("Matching");
  imshow( "Matching", img_matches );

  waitKey(0);
  //return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem too. My issue was I was running Visual Studio 2012, but using the lib files that came openCV(2.4.3) which were built for Visual Studio 2010.

If this is your case you've got 2 options

1. Rebuild the OpenCV library in VS 2012 (this probably isn't the easiest thing to do).
2. Change your Platform Toolset in Visual Studio. Go **Project Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset** and change it to **"Visual Studio 2010 (v100)"**

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same tutorial and have got the same problem and tried all the methods on web without luck. Just now I finally fixed it. It is not quiting displaying that causes the corruption, but returning from the function. In other words, there are some problems with the cleaning process after the block ends in those dlls.

> In my case, the problem is loading a mix of debug dll and release dll.

You can see if you have the same problem by looking carefully at those loading information. To fix that, change property->linker->Input->Additional Dependencies to ONLY Debug or Release. 
make clean and build again. With luck, you will not see the problem again.

Hope it helps.